# How does bundler choose between vendor/bundle/bin and vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

Can anyone shed light on how Ruby bundler is choosing which executable to run for a given gem?

I'm using a Docker container with a bind mount so that the host and the container share the same working directory (a Rails project). Within the container, I see that a different executable gets called than on the host when I `bundle exec which rspec`:

- `/home/me/myproj/vendor/bundle/bin/rspec`
- `/home/me/myproj/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/rspec`

When I run `bundle path`, the result is just `vendor/bundle`. That's not very illuminating.

I'd like the container to use the same gem code as the host. Is there a way for me to configure that?

Answer (score 0):

You can install the gem to a specific path like this

`bundle install --path='vendor/bundle'`

Better

`bundle check --path='vendor/bundle' || bundle install --path='vendor/bundle'`

Ref: https://bundler.io/v0.9/bundle_install.html

Comment: This doesn't really address the issue. I already have the gem installed at `vendor/bundle` (and at `vendor/bundleruby/2.6.0`), and I want to specify which installation gets used when I invoke `bundle exec rspec`. Despite the fact that the container uses one location and the host uses the other location, in both environments `bundle config path` indicates that it's using `vendor/bundle`.